# java get element from webpage into variable

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to get an element from a page into a variable

```
    String url = "http://www.aaaaaaa.com"; 
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    String value = document.body().select("").get(0).text();
```

how to get this into the value

```
<div class="clock-text">12:10:13 pm</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the element you're trying to retrieve will always have the class `clock-text` then you have to change the last line to:

```java
String value = document.body().select(".clock-text").get(0).text()
```

JSoup's select method works with CSS queries.

Answer (score 1):

Selector based on div with class name `clock-text`

```
Elements element = document.select("div.clock-text").first();
```

The `first` matched element, or `null` if contents is empty.

```
String value = element.text();
```